# Material Better Spinner dropdown is not showing compeletely

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-alertdialog, android-spinner

I have used Material Better spinner on Dialog. It works fine if I change the height of dialog to match_parent. I have also used AppcompatSpinner for showing dropdown, but it also does n't work. What I think is my dropdown view is not showing because it was only taking a view of dialog.
[image: Please find attach Image for reference.]

Comment: your spinner is clipping out from the dialog window, can you provide your layout file

Comment: What to do for that?

Comment: try wrapping the picker view in a NestedScrollview with wrap content height, I'm not sure this will work

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: you better off creating a issue in the library's repo. which library are you using?

Comment: I have used appcompactSpinner also but it is not working.

Comment: this is a known bug https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/575